# MSVC 2012 can't see globals

Tags: visual-studio-2012, global-variables

So I confronted with that when I was working on the project. So I decided to check if I could reproduce that in a simple project. So here it is:

```
// main.cpp
#include "TestCase.h"
using namespace Game;

void main()
{
    int t = 1;
    t = gGlobalVar;
    int x = 0; // <------------ put breakpoint here
}

// TestCase.h
#pragma  once

namespace Game
{
    int gGlobalVar = -1;
}
```

Neither in watch window nor in code view I can see the value of the global variable gGlobalVar. Why ? What should I do to bring it to the light side ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told that that behaviour is the old bug of the debugger at it was fixed in the Visual Studio 2015.